# Firebase - Transferred App From iOS Developer to another

Tags: ios, firebase, transfer

I currently have an iOS app where I have used Firebase in for Analytics and Push Notifications. When I transfer this app into another Apple Developer Account, what would happen? Would Firebase still work normally or would I have to change things?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you're going to update some few configuration such as your notification APN certificates on firebase configuration by ensuring that you generate new APN certificates from your new development account and link them into your firebase project.

Comment: So only thr notifications part would be affected. I won't have to change anything like the app's bundle id? And the analytics won't go away?

Comment: Yes forgotten that part, the bundle id would definitely change cause when you create a new provision profile on your account it has to be linked with a proper bundle id of your app and the rest of components you require to use.